# Can't Access Props Outside of Constructor React Native

Tags: react-native, react-props

I'm working on an app in React Native, and am having trouble accessing props that I feed into a component I made.

If I do `console.log(this.props)` within the constructor, I can see the props display in the console as desired, however if I put it in any other method, it prints undefined. How can I access the props that are clearly being sent to the component from outside of the constructor method?

Comment: if it's an event handler you would need to bind it.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my issue!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably adding new methods that are not binding `this`.

Check if you are writing the method like this:

```
myMethod(){
  //Code
}
```

and just change it to:

```
myMethod = () => {
  //Code
}
```

Edit: Like @Li357 says, these are called arrow functions. Arrow functions don't bind this automatically, and as a consequence receive the this of the surrounding class. In your case it will solve your issue as you want to access the properties of that class but you might want to read about it and how binding works in JS classes.

Another option is to write function.bind() but either way should work.

Comment: Your recommendation of using an arrow function isn't standard yet-it would be good to note. Arrow functions don't bind `this` at all, and as a consequence receive the `this` of the surrounding class.

Comment: @Li357 I think using arrow function is also a practical approach instead of binding all functions inside constructor

Comment: @Li357 Fair enough on the "the dont exactly bind this automatically" but "arrow functions is not standard" is way off. They are widely used and provide zero problems with RN.

Comment: @sfratini To clarify, I meant class properties (which include class properties *that are arrow functions*). They AFAIK are not completely standardized as they were merged into the public and private class properties proposal - RN jut provides builtin Babel features. Anyways, the misconception that arrow functions magically bind this is not true.

Comment: @Li357 Ah yeah, understood. I just feel they are so widely used and supported by babel that the warning is not even needed, but noted.

Comment: @sfratini You're right - my fault. I'll be happy to retract my vote if you edit your post.

Comment: @Li357 There you go, I added some notes. Cheers